# Node.js: How to use kafka-node for fetching messages from beginning from a topic?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04) for installing Kafka on Ubuntu 14.04 server. The examples provided for producer and consumer are working fine.

Here is the producer command:

```
echo "Hello, World" | ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TutorialTopic > /dev/null
```

And here is the consumer command:

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TutorialTopic --from-beginning
```

However, I am trying to write a similar consumer in Node.js and it does not display the messages that existed in the topic before the consumer was created. Here is my code. What additional config is required to accomplish what I am trying ?

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node')
var Consumer = kafka.Consumer
var client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181/")
var consumer = new Consumer(
    client,
    [
      { topic: 'TutorialTopic', partition: 0, offset: 0}
    ],
    {
      fromOffset: true
    }
  );


consumer.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log("received message", message);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is that before `consumer.on(...)` is called, your `kafka-node` has already read from the topic. Instead, try this:

```
var consumer = new Consumer(
  client,
  [],
  {fromOffset: true}
);

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log("received message", message);
});

consumer.addTopics([
  { topic: 'TutorialTopic', partition: 0, offset: 0}
], () => console.log("topic added"));
```

Comment: How to get all messages from the TutorialTopic consumer by calling 
 a node url  like 'http://localhost:5001/getMessages' in node js.

Answer (score 3):

The above did not work for me using node v6.11.0 and kafka-node 1.6.2

The following code did:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181/"),
    consumer = new Consumer(
         client,
        [
              { topic: 'TutorialTopic', partition: 0, offset: 0 }
        ],
        { fromOffset: true }         
    );

 consumer.on('message', function (message) 
 {
     console.log(message);
 });

 consumer.on('error', function (err) 
{
    console.log('ERROR: ' + err.toString());
});
```

Comment: hi, i m new to this, could you please tell me where to write the above script? do i need to create new files in specific directories?  @Bertrand_Szoghy

Comment: I go into setup detaisl in my blog posts at bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com, click NodeJs related articles link.

Answer (score 2):

```
Add fromOffset to earliest in consumer config  

var consumer = new Consumer(
client,
[
  { topic: 'TutorialTopic', partition: 0, offset: 0}
],
{
  fromOffset: 'earliest',
});
```